# Cookies blocked by router?

Tags: firewall, cookies

My friend has a D-Link DI-524 router that she uses for her home broadband. It's a pretty vanilla setup with the standard firewall settings, DHCP enabled etc.

However, recently she has experienced something strange - cookies are not working on every computer on her LAN, whether using FF3.5 or IE8.

I tried viewing the HTTP traffic using Fiddler2, and the requests come through fine (mind you, Internet browsing still works flawlessly) but whenever a website tries to set a cookie using the "Set-Cookie:" header, my computer sees that line as "Set-*ookie:" with the cookie contents removed.

I have never seen anything like this - do you have any idea?

Comment: One test, can the computer be plugged directly to the internet, bypassing the router? This should eliminate the possibility (remote) that the router is doing this. Remember that you're also bypassing the firewall, make sure your computer has one as well.

Comment: Did you check you are running the latest firmware on the router?

Answer (score 2):

Based on this description, it sounds like the upstream ISP is running an [interception web proxy](http://oreilly.com/catalog/webcaching/chapter/ch05.html) that is modifying the web server response.  I've heard of this being used to [insert advertisements at the ISP level](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2007/10/web-integrity-checker-isps-inserting-ads-into-web-content/), but there is no reason why it couldn't also be modifying the response headers.  Who is the ISP?

Answer (score 0):

Unless D-Link's firmware has gotten a lot more robust lately, sounds like a filtering proxy.

Comment: interesting.  you mean on the d-link itself, or upstream?  i guess the OP could always experiment with a direct connection.